# html table input integer type?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I made a table where input is integer, but somehow I am still able to pass any text.

```html
<tr>
      <td>number: </td>
      <td><input type="integer" name="number" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
```

is the type="integer" correct?

Comment: The set of `type` values supported is finite and documented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, `integer` is not the correct type - what you seek is `number`

```
<input type='number' />
```

Additional attributes for this type of input are possible, including:

- `min`: the lowest value the input will allow
- `max`: the highest value the input will allow
- `step`: the incremental value that the up/down selectors will increment the current value by

[More information & example usage from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="number" name="number" value="" min="0" step="1"/>
```

Comment: what does min and step mean?

Comment: @MartinŠvejda this will allow only integer

Answer (score 1):

For numeric, you should use `type="number"` . 
For detailed, you can follow [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) .

Your updated code is given as-

```html
<tr>
      <td>number: </td>
      <td><input type="number" name="number" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
```

**Other Solution:** you can do it using `JavaScript` validation as given below.

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  value="" name="number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```